# Introducing function waypoints to protect device

Tags: c++, c

Defining a magic pointer or counter inside a program / class and checking for a fixed value before executing critical commands is a way to generate a barrier against wrong execution.

This check is supposed to be used on an embedded system which runs a program written in C/C++. Imagine a situation where the program counter is set to a dangerous address by mistake (EMI, bad programmer, hacker, Santa...). This piece of code would for example erase a flash cell in the MCU. We do not want that -> Put an if in front of every erase command and check for 0xDEADBEEF.

I know the gain is not too high and the program looses flexibility. I also thought about having waypoints (Erase -> Is write set? -> Do you have firmware data?)

What is this technique called? Are there any papers about it or even patterns?

Comment: If you have some logic that tells you what is dangerous, those checks should be, at the very minimum, inside your `erase` and you should not rely in anything else. What if the hacker finds a way to alter other parameters while letting using other value (v.g., PC is 0xDEADBEEE but the instruction will delete two words).

Comment: that is correct but the software does not intend to be hacker safe, if somebody tries he will eventually find a way to execute those lines. I'm searching for a way to protect the function while still keeping flexibility and maintainability.

Comment: I am sure a real hard core hacker would find a way around your "protection".

Answer (score 3):

A field you add to a structure for the purpose of error checking is often called a *dog tag* (I think it's so called after [Code Complete - Steve McConnel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Complete)).

A dog tag is used to check for corrupted memory:

- when you allocate a variable put a value that should remain unchanged into its tag file;
- when you use the structure check the tag's field value (if the tag field doesn't have the expected value the data has been corrupted);
- when you delete a pointer corrupt the tag so that if you accidentally try to free the same pointer again you'll detect the corruption.

Canary values on the stack are dog tag fields (take a look at [Is “dog-tag” fields used in some software?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771594/is-dog-tag-fields-used-in-some-software)).